# XC Skiing as Cross Training for Running

Tags: running, long-distance-running, marathon, running-training-plan, skiing

I would like to Cross Country Ski this winter as cross training for my next Marathon. My question is if I can ski for a number of hours and will this impact my normal run training? My last marathon I ran 50-60 miles per week but I would like to add some other exercise types to my next cycle of training.

Do I need more than one complete rest day or can I run a long day then ski for a number hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, skiing will impact your normal run training (and vice versa). If you go skiing for a number of hours, you will be doing different biomechanical things, but you will be stressing the same systems. Don't do two long efforts in two days.

Fun fact: elite 5K and 10K runner Ben True was a Nordic skier before focusing entirely on running: http://www.runnersworld.com/tag/ben-true